# Resize DIV by easing?

Tags: jquery

I have a main container div that I want to resize dynamically. In a way that, let's say that a div inside the container suddenly loads a wall of text that expands the div by 500 pixels - I don't want the container div to suddenly become larger, but change size with easing. I am thinking that maybe I could set the overflow to hidden on the container, and then execute some sort of a resize script? What are your thoughts? Thanks :)

[Updated link](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/organictab/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been done before. See http://css-tricks.com/examples/OrganicTabs/

Original Article: http://css-tricks.com/4530-organic-tabs/

Comment: This seems to work except when I add in content through the click of a button the div resizes when when I have overflow set to hidden.

Comment: Did you use his code/plugin/whatever? Added original article.

Comment: Hi Rikudo, thanks for your help had I not found an alternative I would definitely use your solution. I used this in the end :) http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/jXC5U/